# Node-RED How to pass json object out to multi-output function node with Switch & case

Tags: javascript, node-red

To use a function node with multiple Outputs, one can pass the message to the right output as such:

```
switch (msg.payload) {
   case 1:
      var msg1 = {payload: foo.bar} ;
      break;
   case 2: 
      var msg2 = {payload: foo.bar2}
   break;
}
return [msg1,msg2];
```

However, If I want to pass an json object through msg1 / msg2 - it does not pass anything. Neither of the following worked to pass a json object into each of the msg's

```
var msg1 = {'payload.item1': xx, 'payload.item2': xy}; // or
var msg1 = {payload: {'item1': xx, 'item2': xy}};
```

### Any idea of how to pass an object into a multi-output function?

This also did not work:

```
var msg1 = 'a';
var msg2 = 'b';
var msg3 = 'c';

switch (msg.payload){
    case "1":
        msg1 = {payload: {'foo':1,'bar':10}};
        break;
    case "2":
       msg2 = {payload: {'foo':2,'bar':12}};
       break;
    case "3":
       msg1 = {payload: {'foo':3,'bar':13}};
       break;
}

return [msg1,msg2,msg3];
```

Comment: `msg1` and `msg2` are not in scope for the return because they are declared in the `switch` statement so it's the same as `return [undefined, undefined]`

Comment: that makes sense... How do I do it then? Will it work if I declare msg1, msg2 before the switch starts? Will it bring back an object? Let me try it....

Answer (score 0):

Your last example did not work for for a simple reason: you declared msg1, msg2, msg3 and assigned strings to them. Node-RED expects that you always return objects, not strings.

So if you replace :

```
var msg1 = 'a';
var msg2 = 'b';
var msg3 = 'c';
```

by:

```
var msg1 = {};
var msg2 = {};
var msg3 = {};
```

You will not see errors when running the flow, but.. perhaps this may not be exactly what you want. In order to provide a more accurate response it is necessary to ask what would you expect to be delivered on the two outputs that have not been selected by the switch  case ?

A more usual solution, but not in line with you requirement (using a function node with multiple outputs)  would be using a node-RED switch node, like in below flow:

```
[{"id":"741aef4.6e6c91","type":"tab","label":"Flow 4","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"5adb5fe6.46687","type":"switch","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"1","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"2","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"3","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"false","repair":false,"outputs":3,"x":330,"y":160,"wires":[["daac55db.1fcbc8"],["c1d473f8.3e399"],["46b134bc.88338c"]]},{"id":"51cdd5fa.e5c28c","type":"inject","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","topic":"","payload":"1","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":140,"y":120,"wires":[["5adb5fe6.46687"]]},{"id":"235d0c65.794ed4","type":"inject","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","topic":"","payload":"2","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":140,"y":160,"wires":[["5adb5fe6.46687"]]},{"id":"134e5583.3f7a4a","type":"inject","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","topic":"","payload":"3","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":140,"y":200,"wires":[["5adb5fe6.46687"]]},{"id":"daac55db.1fcbc8","type":"change","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"{\"foo\":1,\"bar\":10}","tot":"json"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":510,"y":140,"wires":[["50f4c1a9.ea486"]]},{"id":"c1d473f8.3e399","type":"change","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"{\"foo\":2,\"bar\":12}","tot":"json"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":510,"y":180,"wires":[["cad7dc88.0db57"]]},{"id":"46b134bc.88338c","type":"change","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"{\"foo\":3,\"bar\":13}","tot":"json"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":510,"y":220,"wires":[["6da7761e.5c70f8"]]},{"id":"50f4c1a9.ea486","type":"debug","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":660,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"cad7dc88.0db57","type":"debug","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":660,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"6da7761e.5c70f8","type":"debug","z":"741aef4.6e6c91","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":660,"y":220,"wires":[]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhhhh... makes absolute sense. Let me try it over the eeekend